# Why is the ::before pseudo element going on top on mobile menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu that has a png img as `::before` pseudo-element, and instead of sticking next to menu items, it's going on top.

```js
const menu_button = $('img');
const menu_nav = $('#myNav');

menu_button.click(function(){
  menu_nav.toggleClass('menu_open')
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #d6cece;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 27px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
}

.overlay-content a:before {
  width: 6px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 18px;
  height: 20px;
}

.menu_open {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100">

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why this behavior? It's working without the menu, but not when the elements are vertically aligned. Please check out the snippet I quickly made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the elements are going "on top" because you set `top` to `18px` for all elements.

that wouldn't be a problem if the positioning context for absolute positioning, was set correctly (the a element instead of the `overlay-content` div).

you should set the positioning context to the a element itself:

```
.overlay a { 
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should probably be something like this

```
.overlay-content > a:before { 
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("https://picsum.photos/5") no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

and then change this to

```
.overlay-content a:before {
  width: 6px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 18px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, this didn't change the ::before behaviour at all, it just made the menu look completely different, care to elaborate?

Comment: I had just assumed that you were trying to apply the values just to the a tags within the parents with the class .overlay I'll take a closer look and update my answer

Comment: did that work for you? if it did please confirm the answer

Comment: Not really, sorry.